# Unable to open Facebook login screen

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-facebook

I'm trying to create a Facebook login for an app in Android (iPhone working fine).

This is my `tiapp.xml` (as instructed here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook):

```
 <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
        <application android:theme="@style/Light">
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

I've also added the `strings.xml` resource as needed. But when I try to call the `authorize()` function I get the following error:

> Ucaught Error: Log in attempt failed: FacebookActivity could not be started. Please make sure you added FacebookActivity to the AndroidManifest.

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>`

with

`<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="YourAppName" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" />`

The important thing is to replace `com.facebook.LoginActivity` with `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` activity here, Facebook changed that a few versions ago. For more information, check the [ti.facebook](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook) repository.